# .net core signalR, how to know the group name when a user leaves the group

Tags: .net-core, signalr

I am working on a chat application.
As I understood, a single connection can join multiple groups.
And it works for me.
But when the user leaves one group, I will have to populate the existing user's name in that group.

so I think if I somehow know what is the group name that user left, I can remove that entry from the database.

```
public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception){}
```

I assume this is the place where I have to do the thing.

BUT, how would I know the group name here?? Any ideas?